# the development server returned 500 react native

Tags: react-native

I started a new react-native project and I suddenly got this error for no reason and every time I add a package the app can't read and it shows an error for that package for example react-navigation. I tried reinstalling the app countless times but the problem never got fixed.

[image: Routes][image: App]
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1G7i.png)[image: emulartor]

Comment: Which version of React Native are you on? Also if you're using the most recent React-navigation package, you're importing navigation from the wrong package. I'd suggest following the turorial on the library's getting started. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: I didn't do anything I started a new app and that's the problem I got. Also I'm using the last version of React-navigation and I changed it already like so `import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';` following the docs but I'm still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install **react-native-gesture-handler**.

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

or

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler
```

Comment: I've already installed that I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Did you import it at the top of your App.js file, at the very first line? Even Before react itself. `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`